# addEventListener returns undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want set the `addEventListner` value to int value,

```
const stringItem = window.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  const itemTarget = e.target;
  const itemParent = itemTarget.parentElement.id;
  const strItem = parseInt(itemParent.slice(5));
  console.log(strItem);
  return strItem;
}, false);
let currentItem = stringItem;
console.log(currentItem);
```

*stringItem return **undefined**, but I want the **strItem** to be returned*

I want to access the `strItem` value outside the `addEventListener`.

How do I do that?

Comment: The return value of the callback function is discarded. It doesn't make sense to return anything. Why do you want to return a value? [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value) doesn't return anything. It doesn't make sense to store the result in a variable `stringItem`. What are you trying to achieve? Can you describe your code?

Comment: @jabaa I want to access the strItem value outside that addEventListener

Comment: Create a variable outside of the function and store the value of `strItem` in it.

Comment: Event handlers don't return anything. They allow you to control how events are _handled_. _How_ you handle that information is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **addEventListener** returns undefined as a function (see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value)). You are passing a function to the addEventListener which gets called whenever you click on the window. The return value of that function will be lost. To be able to use that value outside of the function you will have to do something like this:

```
let stringItem;

window.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
const itemTarget = e.target;
const itemParent = itemTarget.parentElement.id;
const strItem = parseInt(itemParent.slice(5));
console.log(strItem);
stringItem = strItem;
return strItem;
}, false);
```

The last two line of your code wouldn't work as they're executed as soon as the eventListener gets added. The currentItem will always be undefined. I would advise you to read more on using callback function in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the callback function is discarded. It doesn't make sense to return anything. `window.addEventListener` doesn't return anything. It doesn't make sense to store the result in a variable `stringItem`.

You can create a variable outside of the function and store the value in it:

```js
let value = 0;

document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  ++value;
}, false);
document.querySelector('#button2').addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  value = 0;
}, false);
document.querySelector('#button3').addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  console.log(value);
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Increment</button>
<button id="button2">Reset</button>
<button id="button3">Show</button>
```